# Bind failed: Address already in use

Tags: c, linux, sockets

I am attempting to bind a socket to a port below:

```
if( bind(socket_desc,(struct sockaddr *) &server, sizeof(server)) < 0)
{
    perror("bind failed. Error");
    return 1;
}
puts("bind done");
```

But it gives:

```
$ ./serve   
Socket created    
bind failed. Error: Address already in use
```

Why does this error occur?

Comment: I faced the same issue when I closed the server program with client program still running. This put the socket into `TIME_WAIT` state. Here's an elaborate discussion of the problem: [How to forcibly close a socket in TIME_WAIT?](http://serverfault.com/questions/329845/how-to-forcibly-close-a-socket-in-time-wait)

Comment: Related question (but for Python): [python - socket.error: \[Errno 48\] Address already in use - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19071512/socket-error-errno-48-address-already-in-use) ■ Refer to [c - Error: Address already in use while binding socket with address but the port number is shown free by `netstat` - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5106674/error-address-already-in-use-while-binding-socket-with-address-but-the-port-num) for the special case where the socket is improperly closed and it's in TIME_WAIT state.)

Answer (score 51, accepted):

The error usually means that the port you are trying to open is being already used by another application. Try using netstat to see which ports are open and then use an available port.

Also check if you are binding to the right ip address (I am assuming it would be localhost)

Comment: It can also be that you are running a web debugging proxy like fiddler (http://www.telerik.com/fiddler).  I was getting that same error on my machine, I closed fiddler, and was able to proceed just fine.

Comment: It can also be that there are leftover ports in TIME-WAIT state. If the IP address was wrong the error would have been 'cannot assign requested address', and the default that should be assumed is not `localhost` but INADDR_ANY.

Comment: For `python` or `python3` based apps, just close all such apps and then proceed. Use `pkill -9 python` & `pkill -9 python3`

Answer (score 96):

Everyone is correct. However, if you're also busy testing your code your **own** application might still "own" the socket if it starts and stops relatively quickly. Try [SO_REUSEADDR](http://www.unixguide.net/network/socketfaq/4.5.shtml) as a socket option:

> What exactly does SO_REUSEADDR do?
>
> This socket option tells the kernel that even if this port is busy (in
>     the TIME_WAIT state), go ahead and reuse it anyway.  If it is busy,
>     but with another state, you will still get an address already in use
>     error.  It is useful if your server has been shut down, and then
>     restarted right away while sockets are still active on its port.  You
>     should be aware that if any unexpected data comes in, it may confuse
>     your server, but while this is possible, it is not likely.
>
> It has been pointed out that "A socket is a 5 tuple (proto, local
>     addr, local port, remote addr, remote port).  SO_REUSEADDR just says
>     that you can reuse local addresses.  The 5 tuple still must be
>     unique!" by Michael Hunter (mphunter@qnx.com).  This is true, and this
>     is why it is very unlikely that unexpected data will ever be seen by
>     your server.  The danger is that such a 5 tuple is still floating
>     around on the net, and while it is bouncing around, a new connection
>     from the same client, on the same system, happens to get the same
>     remote port.  This is explained by Richard Stevens in ``2.7 Please
>     explain the TIME_WAIT state.''.

Comment: https://easyengine.io/tutorials/nginx/troubleshooting/emerg-bind-failed-98-address-already-in-use/

Above link only fixed my problem... Though I used (SO_REUSEADDR | SO_REUSEPORT) both this problem occurred.

Comment: @iDebD_gh SO_REUSEPORT is only for UDP.

Comment: Be aware SO_REUSEADDR can have negative ramifications if the port in question is behind a Load Balancer.

Answer (score 70):

`Address already in use` means that the `port` you are trying to allocate for your current execution is already occupied/allocated to some other process.

> If you are a developer and if you are working on an application which require lots of testing, you might have an instance of your same application running in background (may be you forgot to stop it properly)

So if you encounter this error, just see which application/process is using the port.

In linux try using `netstat -tulpn`. This command will list down a process list with all running processes.

*Check if an application is using your port.* ***If that application or process is another important one then you might want to use another port which is not used by any process/application.***

**Anyway you can stop the process which uses your port and let your application take it.**

If you are in linux environment try,

- Use `netstat -tulpn` to display the processes
- `kill <pid>` This will terminate the process

If you are using windows,

- Use `netstat -a -o -n` to check for the port usages
- Use `taskkill /F /PID <pid>` to kill that process

Comment: kill -9 <pid> for Ubuntu?

Comment: kill -9 is rude ;-). Use it wisely and only when there's no choice.

Answer (score 69):

You have a process that is already using that port. `netstat -tulpn` will enable one to find the process ID of that is using a particular port.

Comment: `netstat: n: unknown or uninstrumented protocol`

Comment: @Dr.jacky I get the same error on macOS. If you try removing the "n", you will get a more helpful message that you need to specify a protocol for that "p". `netstat -tulp TCP` will run, but ultimately it's wrong because the macOS and Linux versions of `netstat` are very different and the parameters mean completely different things. Look for the answers about `lsof` which does the same thing on macOS.

Answer (score 24):

if address is already in use can you just want to kill whoso ever process is using the port, you can use

> **lsof -ti:PortNumberGoesHere | xargs kill -9**

source and inspiration [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/671337).

PS: Could not use netstat because it not installed already.

Answer (score 14):

As mentioned above the port is in use already.
This could be due to several reasons

1. some other application is already using it.
2. The port is in `close_wait` state when your program is waiting for the other end to close the program.refer (https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/10106/orphaned-connections-in-close-wait-state).
3. The program might be in `time_wait` state. you can wait or use socket option `SO_REUSEADDR` as mentioned in another post.

Do `netstat -a | grep <portno>` to check the port state.

Comment: How can we manually stop this application at this port number?

Comment: CLOSE-WAIT means the port is waiting for this end to close it, not the remote end. That's what your link says too.

Comment: `CLOSE_WAIT` means your program is still running, and hasn't closed the socket (and the kernel is waiting for it to do so). 
`SO_REUSEADDR` is for servers and `TIME_WAIT` sockets, so doesn't apply here

Comment: Windows: 
`netstat -ano | findstr ":8080"` (to find pid - last column - for port) and then
`taskkill /F /PID <pid>` to kill the process with the pid.

Answer (score 2):

It also happens when you have not give enough permissions(read and write) to your sock file!

Just add expected permission to your sock contained folder and your sock file:

```
 chmod ug+rw /path/to/your/
 chmod ug+rw /path/to/your/file.sock
```

Then have fun!

Answer (score 2):

Check for running process pid:

```
pidof <process-name>
```

Kill processes:

```
sudo kill -9 process_id_1 process_id_2 process_id_3
```

Answer (score 1):

I was also facing that problem, but I resolved it.
**Make sure that both the programs for client-side and server-side are on *different projects* in your IDE,** in my case NetBeans. Then assuming you're using localhost, I recommend you to implement both the programs as *two different projects*.

Answer (score 1):

First of check which port are listening,

```
netstat -tlpn
```

then select available port to conect,

```
sudo netstat -tlpn | grep ':port'
```

Fix it into also to your server and clients interfaces. Go  Barrier tab -> change settings, -> port value type -> save/ok

[image]

> Check both clients and server have similar port values

**Then Reload.**

Now it should be ok.

Answer (score 0):

To terminate all node processes:

```
killall -9 node
```

Answer (score -1):

I was supposed to create a tunnel using `ssh -L` option, leave it running in a terminal, and then use `ssh -p` in another terminal to make an ssh connection via the tunnel.

I did a `ctrl+r`, which usually gets me the `ssh -p`. But, since I restarted my laptop the `ctrl+r` just gave me the `ssh -L` command again.

So, I was doing `ssh -L` twice and wondering why the second command was not working :-P