# linux: port bind failure

Tags: linux, bind

I'm running a linux application which calls **bind** for a port created with **socket**

```
int sockAddrSize = sizeof (struct sockaddr_in);

m_Socket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
if (m_Socket < 0)
{
    printf ("CTcpServer::Open : socket failed\n");
    return -1;
}

memset ((char *) &m_ServerAddress, 0,sizeof (sockaddr_in)); 

m_ServerAddress.sin_family = AF_INET; 
    m_ServerAddress.sin_port = htons (Port); 
m_ServerAddress.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl (INADDR_ANY);

if (bind (m_Socket, (struct sockaddr *)&m_ServerAddress, sockAddrSize)<0)
{
    printf ("Open: bind failed. errno=Unknown\n");
    return -1;
}

if (listen (m_Socket,1)<0)
{
    printf ("CTcpServer::Open : listen failed. errno=Unknown\n");
    return -1;
}

socklen_t sockAddrSize = sizeof (struct sockaddr_in);
sockaddr_in  ClientAddress;

m_ListenSocket = accept(m_Socket, (struct sockaddr *) &ClientAddress, &sockAddrSize);
if (m_ListenSocket < 0)
{
    printf ("CTcpClient::AcceptConnection : accept failed. errno=Unknown\n");
    return -1;
}
```

After **accept** the application is blocked till client establishes a connection.

At this point, if I break the application (Ctrl C) and then tries to run it again, the **bind** fails:
*errno=98 Address already in use*

It happens also if the application quits in case of segmentation fault (BUG in the application)

It seems that the port is still open.

Can you please tell why ?  The application was killed - not gracefully.
Same scenario under windows works.

Thank you,
Zvika

Comment: In particular, this answer from that duplicate post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15199016/3003365

Comment: Thank you very much !  if setsockopt(m_Socket, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, ...) is used before bind, it works.